# serial data gets spoiled

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, python, raspberrypi

I use this small program on my Raspberry Pi to recieve a string sent by my arduino.

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

def check_for_command():
    bytestoread = ser.inWaiting()
    if bytestoread != 0:
        temp = ser.read(bytestoread)
        print(temp)

while 1:
    check_for_command()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

the code on the arduino is rather simple:

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
Serial.println(“Hello Pi”);
delay(2000);
```

the annoying part is. I recieve this:

> b'Hello Pi\r\n'

instead of the clean

> Hello Pi

How do I get rid of those extra bits without using a list for each character.

Thank in advance!

Comment: The python code does not need to be anywhere near this complicated.  Once you open the device to the handle ser, then all you need is --
 linenin=ser.readline() --- and it is good that you are using -- Serial.println -- on the Arduino that sends the \n character at the end of the string so it will work just fine.  Then all you need in Python is --  print linein -- to see what you have received.  Nothing complicated is required.  Just treat it like a file, and remember that ser.readline() is a blocking function.  It will stop everything and wait for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `b` prefix in Python 3 just means that it is a `bytes` literal. It's not part of the output, that's just telling you the type.

The `\r\n` is a common Carriage-Return and Newline line-ending characters. You can remove that from your string by calling `strip()`.

Since these are floating-point numbers being returned, I'm guessing you're going to want to use them in some way after they are read, too:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
   value = float(ser.readline().strip())
   print('New value is {0:0.2f}'.format(value))
```

See also:

- [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: trying to use your lines it gives me a format error on the last line. just before the .format

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error?

Comment: fixed that error found a new one that sometimes occurs, the first problem was: I am using python 3 so `print` needs brackets. :)      the other error is when by accident serial chains two numbers:  `ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'21.020.5'`

Comment: I have updated my code to include python 3 style prints.

Comment: and now you suggest a try and catch to avoid the ValueError?

Comment: The ValueError occurs only when serial chains two numbers, right? In that case you could either use a try and catch or increase the delay in Arduino's loop.

Comment: if I would like to send a string instead of a float and want to get rid off the b prefix? changing float into string doesnt work.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
temp = ser.readline(bytestoread).decode('ascii')
```

instead of

```
temp = ser.read(bytestoread)
```

Answer (score -1):

As the bytes sent by Raspbian is encoded in UTF-8, use the following line in order to avoid a strip() at a later-on stage:

```
temp = ser.read(bytestoread).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Well, it's not the Raspi sending but the Arduino. And `decode()` does *not* strip the '\r\n' from the decoded string.